# How do I write Angular 8's equivalent of jQuery's ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angular, typescript, angular8

So I am transitioning from plain old html and javascript for my webapp to Angular. As such my javascript ajax calls to my php server controller need to be rewritten for Angular. How do I go about doing that? I am new to writing ajax calls in jQuery and new to Angular 8.

jQuery ajax code that I want to write in AngularTS form

```
$.ajax({
      data:     DATA,
      url:      '../upgrade/controller/app_validateManager.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      type:     'POST',

        beforeSend: function(x) {
          if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
            x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            }
        },  

        success: function(data){
            console.log("works")
            if (data.status == 0)
              {
              alert('Response >> '+data.datr[0]);
              // window.location.href = redirectLink;
              }
            else{
             console.log(prockey + " error")
             console.log(data)
             for(i=0;i<data.errpos.length;i++){
                  $('#err'+data.errpos[i]).innerHtml = data.errmsg[i]
                }
            }
         },
         error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
          //Here the status code can be retrieved like;
          xhr.status;
          //The message added to Response object in Controller can be retrieved as following.
          xhr.responseText;
      }
    });
```

What I tried:

```
// Angular Service code:
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json;charset=UTF-8"',
  })
};

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }
  // return an observable with a user-facing error message
  return throwError(
    'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }

  ajaxEngine(DATA: PostData): Observable<PostData> {
  console.log(DATA);
    return this.httpClient.post<PostData>(this.phpurl, DATA, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

// Angular Component code:
    this.mainService.ajaxEngine(new PostData(newDATA))
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('works' + data);
        this.postData = data;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
```

Comment: You are on the right path. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @KiraAG I am stuck trying to figure out the success and error part. In jquery ajax there is xhr, what is the equivalent in Angular?

Comment: Look into this for [error-handling](https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling). Here you have error object which has all the info regarding to the error. And also the error object is of type [HttpErrorResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse). So you can retrieve the info you lookin for by using properties mentioned in it.

Comment: @KiraAG Alrighty thanks! I'll go take a look then update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ajax from rxjs/ajax which creates an observable for an ajax request and then subscribe to it to access received data or handle errors, follow this link for more details :
[rxjs ajax](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/ajax.html)